# ¿Por qué no puedo guardar el valor de un radio button en php con mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy guardando un formulario en una tabla usuarios, el los inputs se me guardan de forma correcta pero me di cuenta que los radio buttons no se están guardando

> Este es mi formulario

[image: Esta es mi formulario]

> y este es el error que capturé

[image: El error]

Este es el código que uso en el

> formulario.php

```
     <head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Guardartodo").click(function(){
    var parametros={
        "user":$("#user").val(),
        "password":$("#password").val(),
        "nombre":$("#nombre").val(),
        "apellido":$("#apellido").val(),
        "rut":$("#rut").val(),
        "idperfil":$("#idperfil").val(),
        "pepe":$("#pepe").val(),
        "estado":$("#estado").val(),
        "permisos":$("#permisos").val(),
        "permisos2":$("#permisos2").val(),
        "permisos3":$("#permisos3").val(),
        "opcion":"Guardartodo"
    }
        $("#Guardar2").click(function(){
    var parametros={
        "rut":$("#rut").val(),
        "curso":$("#curso").val(),
        "opcion":"Guardar2"
    }

    $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: "opcion.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
            });

        });

    $("#Buscar2").click(function(){
        var parametros={
        "tipo_atra":$("#atra").val(),
        "opcion":"Buscar2"
        }

        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: "opcion.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#tabla").html(response);
            }
            });

        });



        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: "opcion.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
            });

        });
});
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">

                                    <form id="wizard_with_validation" name="wizard_with_validation" method="post" action="">

<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-label">Nombre*</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-label">Apellido*</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
        <input type="text" id="rut" name="rut" placeholder="Ingrese su RUN" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="12"/>
        <label class="form-label"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Perfil</p>
<input type="radio" id="idperfil1" name="idperfil" class="radio-col-red" value="1" onclick="pepe.value='Administrador'; pepe.disabled=true" checked />
<label for="idperfil1">Administrador</label>
<input type="radio" id="idperfil2"name="idperfil" class="radio-col-indigo" value="2" onclick="pepe.value='Profesor'; pepe.disabled=true" />
<label for="idperfil2">Profesor</label>
<input type="radio" id="idperfil3" name="idperfil" class="radio-col-green" value="3" onclick="pepe.value='Administrativo'; pepe.disabled=true" />
<label for="idperfil3">Administrativo</label>
<input type="radio" id="idperfil4" name="idperfil" class="radio-col-deep-purple" value="4" onclick="pepe.value='Apoderado'; pepe.disabled=true" />
<label for="idperfil4">Apoderado</label>

<input type="hidden" id="pepe" name="pepe" class="form-control" /> 
<script src="js/jquery.rut.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
        <p>Estado*</p>
        <input id="estado1" name="estado" type="radio" class="radio-col-red" value="Activo" checked />
        <label for="estado1">Activo</label>
        <input id="estado2" name="estado" type="radio" class="radio-col-indigo" value="Inactivo" />
        <label for="estado2">Inactivo</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="demo-checkbox">
                                      <h3>Notas</h3>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="permisos31" name="permisos3" value="1" class="chk-col-green"  />
                                <label for="permisos31">Ver</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="permisos32" name="permisos3" value="2" class="chk-col-orange"  />
                                <label for="permisos32">Modificar</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="permisos33" name="permisos3" value="3" class="chk-col-red"  />
                                <label for="permisos33">Eliminar</label>
                                </div>
                                </table>
                                </form><br>

                                <input type="button" id="Guardartodo" name="Guardartodo" value="Guardar todo" class="btn btn-primary" />
<br>
<h1><div id="resultado" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></h1>
                                <input type="button" id="Guardartodo" name="Guardartodo" value="Enviar">
```

Y las recibo en

> opcion.php

```
<?php

include_once "clase_comuna.php";

$objeto= new persona;
$opcion=$_POST["opcion"];

if ($opcion=="Guardartodo") 
{
    $user=$_POST["user"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
    $rut=$_POST["rut"];
    $idperfil=$_POST["idperfil"];
    $pepe=$_POST["pepe"];
    $estado=$_POST["estado"];
    $objeto->Guardartodo($user,$password,$nombre,$apellido,$rut,$idperfil,$pepe,$estado);

    echo "Se ha guardado!!!";
    echo $idperfil;
    echo $estado;
    echo $rut;

}
?>
```

y utiliza por ultimo

> clase_comuna.php

```
<?php

include_once("conexion2.php");

class persona extends Conexion{


     var $user;
     var $password;
     var $nombre;
     var $apellido;
     var $rut;
     var $idperfil;
     var $pepe;
     var $estado;
     var $permisos;
     var $permisos2;
     var $permisos3;


    function log()
    {
        $this->Conexion();
    }

    function Guardartodo($user,$password,$nombre,$apellido,$rut,$idperfil,$pepe,$estado)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios(id_perfil,user,password,nombre_user,apellido_user,rut_user,cargo_usuario,estado) VALUES ('$idperfil', '$user', '$password', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$rut', '$pepe', '$estado')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Has puesto solo parte de HTML que genera el formulario, tus errores están en la parte que lo recibe , falta que pongas el código PHP. Los errores son porque usas variables. Mismo problema en este hilo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index
El caso es que tienes un valor "checked" en ambos selects, tiene que llegar un valor al servidor, no lo estas recogiendo bien.

Comment: Imagino que estás enviando un POST vía jQuery al servidor, pero dentro de la data no hay nada que se llame `idperfil` ni nada que se llame `estado`. ¿Puedes adicionar el código jQuery/Ajax a la pregunta, o la forma en que haces el POST...?

Comment: Hol @A.Cedano gracias por tu aclaración, acabo de insertar en el post lo que utilizo

Comment: @Orici las variables que uso para los radios? acabo de modificar el código en el post

Comment: Tienes al menos **dos botones con el mismo id:** `id="Guardartodo" ` eso no puede ser, el id debe ser distinto, si no jQuery se confunde y podría darte problemas. Verifica que cada id sea distinto en cada elemento y si sigue fallando comenta.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he corregido dejando solo un botón  de enviar, y me sigue dando el mismo error. No me reconoce las dos selecciones en los radios, idperfil y estado

Comment: En jQuery tú estás haciendo esto: `"idperfil":$("#idperfil").val(),` pero en tu HTML no hay nada que tenga un id llamado `idperfil` y lo mismo sucede con `estado`. **Lo que jQuery busca cuando usas `#` es el `id` del elemento, no el nombre.**

Comment: @A.Cedano es que si dejo los radios con el mismo id no se pueden seleccionar uno u otro, no sabría como hacerle referencia

Comment: No he captado bien lo que quieres hacer, pero a los radio puedes darle el mismo nombre y determinar por jQuery aquellos del mismo nombre que están seleccionados o no, usando `checked`. Puedes ver [ejemplos en la página de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/). Por ejemplo: `if( $('input[name=myradiobutton]:radio:checked').length > 0 ) {
        return $('input[name=myradiobutton]:radio:checked').val();
    }
`

Comment: Solo quiero guardar el "value" del radio button seleccionado, he intentado con los ejemplos pero sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Si quieres obtener el valor del radio button seleccionado, puedes hacerlo por ejemplo así: `$('input[name=radioperfil]:checked').val()` lo que se suele hacer es darle el mismo nombre a un grupo de radio buttons y haciendo como indicado más arriba te obtiene el valor de **aquel** que está seleccionado solamente, no sé si eso es lo que quieres. Creo que todos tus radio buttons relativos a perfil pueden tener el mismo nombre y chequeas el valor del que esté seleccionado de ese modo.

Comment: Ha funcionado perfecto con $('input[name=radioperfil]:checked').val(), te lo agradezo

Comment: Convendría dar una respuesta y que la marques como solucionada para que la pregunta no aparezca abierta y sin respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Funcionó perfecto con `$('input[name=radioperfil]:checked').val()`